# Azure WebSites using new Virtual Network Integration features failed to connect to SQL Server in VM machine

Tags: azure-web-app-service, iaas, azure-vpn

I tried to configure a VPN with default values (10.0.1.x) with a point-to-site feature configured. 
Azure Websites has been configured too, using the new Azure portal, to point to the Point-to-Site of the VPN.

When a try to contact SQL server of my VM in Azure (Iaas) fails, while locally on the VM I can do it.

I also configured an end point for the port 1433 on the VM with the relative firewall configuration.

Is there a way to check where is the issue using the website ?
Thanks a lot.
Fabio